# Node.js / Websockets - Adding security to server - html client connection

Tags: node.js, security, websocket, server

I've created a websocket server using node.js and the ws module:

```
var options = {
    port: 8080,
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.cert'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.pem'),
    requestCert: false,                  
    rejectUnauthorized: true
}

var processRequest = function(req, res) {
    console.log("Request received.")
};

var server = https
.createServer( options, processRequest)
.listen(options.port, function(){
    console.log("HTTPS server created and listening to port " + options.port);
});

var wss = new WebSocket.Server
({
    server: server
});
```

And here is a simple HTML client:

```
conn = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:8080'); 
conn.onopen = function(e) {
     console.log("Connection established!");
};
conn.onmessage = function(e) {
     console.log(e.data);
};
conn.onclose = function(e) {
     console.log('connection closed');
}
```

I've also added this to the client's index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' https://example.com/ https://code.jquery.com/ data: gap: ws: wss: ssl.gstatic.com ;">
```

What I want is to add even more security than just the wss protocol to this and all other potential connections. I don't want my server to simply accept any client.

I've tried my luck with `verifyClient` from the `WebSocket.Server` class from ws but I'm getting lost trying to figure out anything that concerns the websocket handshake.

I've also thought of adding a function that checks if the client sends a specific encoded message on connection. But that can only happen AFTER the connection is established so i doubt it's safe.

Could someone help me add further security measures to my wss connections?